# Foxx applications - Remote Debugging / Breakpoints

Tags: debugging, arangodb, foxx

I'm developing an application using ArangoDB V2.8 + foxx and I need to debug / and running the javascript code with the traditional breakpoints.

Is there any foxx option or external framework that allows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that this [is on our feature requests list](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1538), but it isn't implemented yet.

So at the time being the best option is to add debug log output to your foxx services using `console.log()` as [pointed out in the official Foxx documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Foxx/).

Comment: OK, this is what I'm doing. Thanks for your answer!